# pg_dumpall without dropping the superuser

Tags: postgresql, database-restore, postgresql-9.6, pg-dumpall

I have a postgres 9.6. I am using `pg_dumpall` with `-c --if-exists` options.

When I restore from this backup file as the superuser I am getting errors `current user cannot be dropped` when it tries to drop the role. And after that I am getting `role "mysuperuser" already exists` when it tries to create the superuser role.

These two errors does not effect the success of the restore. However, I do not want to get irrelevant errors like these.

What I can do is to remove the two lines which are dropping and creating the aforementioned superuser role.

Is there a better way to do this? Because in order to achieve that I need to open a huge file and edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to join one of the postgreql.org mailing list and see if this irritation has occurred for others. It's clearly not the ideal behaviour.

There is a simple work-around though. Create a new superuser (that doesn't exist in the backup) and use that user to do the restore.

Comment: this solution not works in my case. Postgres 10 returns this error: 
ERROR:  cannot drop role postgres because it is required by the database system